# Custom Raspberry Pi OS File System

Tags: assembly, filesystems, arm, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write an OS for my Raspberry Pi with assembly code and I want to implement a file system. I cannot find out how to read or write data to the SD card.

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: My question is how do I (in assembly code) tell the processor how to write data stored in RAM to the SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing trivial and time consuming.

You need to study `e.MMC` standard from JEDEC to understand how host and card side works. You can get the documents free from their site for a registration.

You then also need to understand how the connection is made to that eMMC host interface. That would be probably lead you to work with `SPI`.

Best would be to get what's available from open source projects like [Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/mmc) or [uBoot](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;f=drivers/mmc;hb=HEAD).